# Best Way To Unpivot a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data that is missing values on weekends, public holidays etc.

```
 datadate  | id | Value 
-----------------------
1999-12-31 | 01 |  1.0 
1999-12-31 | 02 |  0.5
1999-12-31 | 03 |  3.2
2000-01-04 | 01 |  1.0
2000-01-04 | 02 |  0.7
2000-01-04 | 03 |  3.2
```

And I want to copy the values down over the dates for which the data is missing. So, I've pivoted the frame, re-indexed, and copied the values down.

```
 datadate  | 01  | 02  | 03 
----------------------------
1999-12-31 | 1.0 | 0.5 | 3.2
2000-01-01 | 1.0 | 0.5 | 3.2
2000-01-02 | 1.0 | 0.5 | 3.2
2000-01-03 | 1.0 | 0.5 | 3.2
2000-01-04 | 1.0 | 0.7 | 3.2
```

Now I want to return the data to its original form. I've tried using `pd.melt()`, and `df.unstack()`, but I'm ending up with more columns than I want, and constructing a new data frame from the result is taking a long time.

Is there a better way to unpivot the data ?

Comment: "more columns than I want" -- what does that mean? you should have a column for every unique value in `id`. What do you actually want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `pandas.pivot_table` function and if you define `datadate` and `id` as indices, you can do `unstack` the dataframe.

That'd be:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas

datatable = StringIO("""\
datadate  | id | Value 
1999-12-31 | 01 |  1.0 
1999-12-31 | 02 |  0.5
1999-12-31 | 03 |  3.2
2000-01-04 | 01 |  1.0
2000-01-04 | 02 |  0.7
2000-01-04 | 03 |  3.2""")

fullindex = pandas.DatetimeIndex(freq='1D', start='1999-12-31', end='2000-01-06')
df = (
    pandas.read_table(datatable, sep='\s+\|\s+', parse_dates=['datadate'])
          .set_index(['datadate', 'id'])
          .unstack(level='id')
          .reindex(fullindex)
          .fillna(method='ffill')
          .stack()
          .reset_index()
          .rename(columns={'level_0': 'date'}) 
)

print(df)
```

Which gives me:

```
         date  id  Value
0  1999-12-31   1    1.0
1  1999-12-31   2    0.5
2  1999-12-31   3    3.2
3  2000-01-01   1    1.0
4  2000-01-01   2    0.5
5  2000-01-01   3    3.2
6  2000-01-02   1    1.0
7  2000-01-02   2    0.5
8  2000-01-02   3    3.2
9  2000-01-03   1    1.0
10 2000-01-03   2    0.5
11 2000-01-03   3    3.2
12 2000-01-04   1    1.0
13 2000-01-04   2    0.7
14 2000-01-04   3    3.2
15 2000-01-05   1    1.0
16 2000-01-05   2    0.7
17 2000-01-05   3    3.2
18 2000-01-06   1    1.0
19 2000-01-06   2    0.7
20 2000-01-06   3    3.2
```

(I like chaining)

Comment: I think the OP wants it the other way ? pv to df. I think you can do that with melt, but it seems messy!

Comment: I think unstacking, re-indexing, and fillna-ing is what needs to happen. I missed the part about filling missing dates. I think we just had too small of a example dataset

Comment: who doesn't love chaining! FWIW I prefer to use parenthesis rather than \ on every line (I hate those! :p).

Answer (score 1):

You can  achieve this by setting the propper attributes in the melt function like this:

```
datedate  01   02   03
0  1999-12-31   1  0.5  3.2
1  2000-01-01   1  0.5  3.2
2  2000-01-02   1  0.5  3.2
3  2000-01-03   1  0.5  3.2
4  2000-01-04   1  0.5  3.2

df_unpivoted = df.melt(id_vars=['datedate'], var_name='id', value_name='value')

datedate  id  value
0   1999-12-31  01    1.0
1   2000-01-01  01    1.0
2   2000-01-02  01    1.0
3   2000-01-03  01    1.0
4   2000-01-04  01    1.0
5   1999-12-31  02    0.5
6   2000-01-01  02    0.5
7   2000-01-02  02    0.5
8   2000-01-03  02    0.5
9   2000-01-04  02    0.5
10  1999-12-31  03    3.2
11  2000-01-01  03    3.2
12  2000-01-02  03    3.2
13  2000-01-03  03    3.2
14  2000-01-04  03    3.2
```

In the following link you can find a more detailed example:

https://dfrieds.com/data-analysis/melt-unpivot-python-pandas